# missing coordinates in nested loop

Tags: python, loops

```
grid=400
P1=[]

for i in range(grid+1):
    P1.append(i/grid)

x=[]
y=[]
z=[]

for j in range(len(P1)):
    for k in range(len(P1)):
        for l in range(len(P1)):
            if P1[j] + P1[k] + P1[l] == 1.0:
                x.append(P1[j])
                y.append(P1[k])
                z.append(P1[l])
```

I'm making a ternary grid and I noticed that some of the coordinates were missing. I'm pretty sure the condition is right and I get random coordinates missing when I construct with different grid size

for example in a 400 grid size, an example of a missing coordinates were as below:-

```
....
0.5025,0.29,0.2075
0.5025,0.2975,0.2
0.5025,0.3,0.1975
....
```

(0.5025,0.2925,0.205) and (0.5025,0.295,0.2025) were missing. any idea to solve this?

Comment: don't compare floats with ==

Comment: consider using something like [`numpy.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)

Comment: is there any way around it? if i were to put =, it would a syntax error then

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

grid=400
P1=[i/grid for i in range(grid+1)]
epsilon = 0.001

x=[]
y=[]
z=[]
coords = [x,y,z]

for vals in itertools.product(P1, P1, P1)
    if abs(sum(vals)-1) >= epsilon: continue  # this epsilon value will correct for the variations due to floating point arithmetic
    for L,v in zip(coords, vals): L.append(v)
```